# Запись в таблицу не больше 30 строк

Tags: php, javascript, html

Через PHP формирую таблицу. Требуется чтобы в этой таблице было не больше 30 строк, хотя выборка из БД может быть очень большой.
Желательно просто иметь всю выборку на стороне клиента но отображать по 30 строк.
Также удобный переход на другую стопку записей, тоже по 30 строк.

Как удобней это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужно только 30 записей, то делайте так:

```
<?

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dataase');
$query = $db->query('select * from posts order by id desc limit 30');

$query = $query->fetch_all();

echo '<table>';
foreach ($query as $item) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $item[0] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $item[1] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $item[2] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

или сделать `json_encode(array_chunk($query, 30));`.

Можно вернуть такой `json` на frontend и уже через `$.each()` прогонять массив.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery плагин https://www.datatables.net/ - пагинация, сортировка и прочие плюшки.

Comment: ммм прикольно спс.   А если ручками делать теоретическая схему выполнения какая?